# How to open file securely?

Tags: c#, winforms, file, security, directory

**Current situation**

I have a folder that has a permission set to `Read` for all users expect for me.

**Current method to view the file**

Currently I use this line of code to view the file`Process.Start(data.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString());` - this is simply a path taken from the `dataGridView`.

**File formats**

There are number of file extensions, such as word, excel, pdf or jpg images.

**Current protection**

Currently, nobody can overwrite the document, due to folder set to `Read`.. but they are able to print the document.

**Desired protection**

What would be a good way to prevent users to print the document when viewing the file? Using `C# Windows Forms`?

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to prevent users from printing the document if they can read it. If they have read rights they could save the document under a new name and have all rights to the new documents, including to print it.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It is named as Read-Only. I think just previewing the file using Windows Form window would achieve this task, what do you think?